# Placing a Module to a Certain Block in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-7, block

I'm new to drupal and familiar with Joomla and Wordpress. I'm little bit confused with how drupal works when placing some kind of module to a certain block in drupal 7. Say that I want to place the search box in a footer block of the theme, what are the steps for doing that?. Or may be is it depending on the theme how modules will be placed. Please guide...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 7 have "Regions" , it's like a grid , you can add block in regions. You can add block via admin interface /admin/structure/block/add , you a part for regions who can receive your block.

Also if you need to create a custom block programmatically, you can follow this link https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/easy-way-to-create-blocks-programmatically

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your answer. I know that Region is like a grid system and I could assign blocks in that regions. However what I couldn't understand is how can I assign any kind of module to a block ? Say that I have the footer region and it contains block1, so that I want to assign a module(such as the search box) to that block. How can I do this ?. Please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a module you'll assign to a block , it's module who produce block to assign to region. You need to create a module , with a custom block declaration (link in my answer) , and develop what you want into this block. Otherwise if you use a contrib module you have to check if it bring you a block.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal uses blocks and they can be placed in regions. Regions are defined in your theme info file and printed from your theme page template.

You can place existing blocks to some regions at "Structure -> Blocks" admin page.

When you are on blocks page there is a table where every row is for a single block. You can place block to some region by dragging it to some region or by changing drop-down in it's Region column (don't forget to save after that).

Also, you can configure every block to be displayed by specific criteria (page, user role...). On same blocks page there is "configure" link for every block and on configure page there is "Visibility" section at bottom of edit page.

But you can use additional modules like *Context* to place blocks to region with more choices.